# How can I parse html google search result?

Tags: html, flutter, parsing

https://www.google.com/search?q=%EB%8D%94%ED%81%B0%EB%8F%84%EC%8B%9C%EB%9D%BD%20%EC%A0%84%EC%A3%BC%EB%8C%80%EC%A0%90%20%EC%A0%84%EB%B6%81%20%EC%A0%84%EC%A3%BC%EC%8B%9C%20%EC%99%84%EC%82%B0%EA%B5%AC%20%EC%B2%9C%EC%9E%A0%EB%A1%9C%20303%20%EB%84%A4%EC%9D%B4%EB%B2%84myplace

is the result that I want to parse.

the problem is...I can't parse first row of search result.

below is how I did it in code.

```
  final naverUserAgentHeader = {
    HttpHeaders.userAgentHeader:
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.122 Safari/537.36'
  };

final response = await http.get(uri, headers: naverUserAgentHeader);

 Document document = parser.parse(response.body);
 List<Element> classList = document.getElementsByClassName("jGGQ5e");
for (int i = 0; i < classList.length; i++) {
  if(classList[i]
            .getElementsByTagName("div").length!=0){
 var aaa = classList[i]
            .getElementsByTagName("div")[0].text;
                    print("aaa...!");
        print(aaa);

            }
}
```

[image]

Comment: How about `console.log([...document.querySelectorAll("#search span")].map(span => span.textContent).join("\n"))`